# What characters need escaping in <textarea>?

Tags: html, textarea

As far as I can tell, this renders perfectly fine:

```css
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<textarea>
  foo<b>bar</b>baz
  <script>
    alert('x');
  </script>
  &lt;/textarea>
  quux
</textarea>
```

i.e., the `<b>` and the `<script>` don't need escaping.

Am I right in assuming that *everything* except `</textarea>` is allowed?

Comment: Yes - and if you somehow manage to follow section 8.2.4 of W3C HTML (which took me a couple of minutes at the very least) you'll find that this behavior is indeed well-specified.

Comment: The only caveat is that you do need to escape any ampersands that would *otherwise* start an invalid or unwanted character reference.

Comment: [§8.2.4 Tokenization](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#tokenization)